# how to enable HTTP request header on Apache 2.4.46

Tags: php, apache, fpm

how to enable HTTP request header on Apache 2.4.46 with PHP-FPM 7.4

I'm unable to read custom http header, which run on local with Apache + mode_php

apache_request_headers();

is there any alternative or is there a way to enable it

Comment: Please provide why you are unable to do it. Are you facing any error? If so please post the error you get and some code around this line

Comment: okay resolved now, is it correct way

Comment: I can't find a duplicate question covering this properly, but it sounds like you're issue is not with apache_request_headers() in general, but with a particular header which has an underscore in its name. These are problematic because of the way headers map to environment variables in the CGI standard, so are dropped by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I got like this
I have change request header X_PJAX from dash to underscore

```
add this in .htacess file

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_X_PJAX:%{HTTP:X_PJAX}]
```

and then access with prefix HTTP

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_X_PJAX"];
```